# How can I get battery consumption in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm developing an app that needs the amount of battery used. I think it's impossible to do with BatteryManager or Battery Historian. Is there any method that can get battery consumption?
It's better to bring battery consumption for each app, but it's okay to bring total battery consumption.

Answer (score 0):

While you are running your app from android studio, you can use "profiler" tool for checking how device reacts to your app, including: RAM consumption, data and energy (battery)

Take a look:
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/energy-profiler

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. But I want to know how much the battery was used by other applications or how much the cell phone battery was worn out within a certain period of time.

Comment: @SJSJ You can use battery settings from the phone itself. The menu is different for each manufactor, but you can search for "battery" or "energy" inside phone settings. You'll find a graph with battery consuption over time and, i believe that for all manufactors, you'll find battery consuption per app.